# blackjack setting image to JLabel

Tags: java, image, file, jframe, selection

This is the full code block of the method that I am trying to use. The selection statements below determine which card to use but I want to set the card based on this? How do I make this work? I can't seem to set a jLabel icon to anything at the moment.
Cheers :)

```
public void run() throws IOException{

    Random rnd = new Random();

    int[] CardValues = new int[]{11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10};

    HCard1 = rnd.nextInt(13) +1;
    HCard2 = rnd.nextInt(13) +1;

    HSuit1 = rnd.nextInt(4);
    HSuit2 = rnd.nextInt(4);
    //Clubs = 0 Diamonds = 1 Hearts = 2 Spades = 3

    PCard1 = (HSuit1 * 13) + (HCard1);
    PCard2 = (HSuit2 * 13) + (HCard2);

    System.out.println("Card: " + HCard1 + "     Suit: " + HSuit1 + "     Pic: " + PCard1);
    System.out.println("Card: " + HCard2 + "     Suit: " + HSuit2 + "     Pic: " + PCard2);


    if (PCard1 <= 13){
        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blackjack/zCards/Clubs/" + PCard1 + ".png")));
    } else if (PCard1 <= 26){
        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blackjack/zCards/Diamonds/" + PCard1 + ".png")));
    } else if (PCard1 <= 39){
        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blackjack/zCards/Hearts/" + PCard1 + ".png")));
    } else if (PCard1 <= 52){
        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blackjack/zCards/Spades/" + PCard1 + ".png")));
    }

    if (PCard2 <= 13){
        jLabel4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blackjack/zCards/Clubs/" + PCard2 + ".png")));
    } else if (PCard2 <= 26){
        jLabel4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blackjack/zCards/Diamonds/" + PCard2 + ".png")));
    } else if (PCard2 <= 39){
        jLabel4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blackjack/zCards/Hearts/" + PCard2 + ".png")));
    } else if (PCard2 <= 52){
        jLabel4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blackjack/zCards/Spades/" + PCard2 + ".png")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well.. what's "not working" in this case? Do you get an exception? Where are your image files located? Are they packaged correctly? Give some more input please... and Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: So what I am trying to do is set a image icon for a jLabel for 1 of the 52 cards in the deck. But it's not doing anything with no errors. I tried another method using IO and another using flush and neither I can get to work. My images are packaged in blackjack.zCards.[Suit name] (4 different packages)
@Jan

Comment: You might want to try splitting it up -> retrieve resource -> print if null -> create image -> check if null -> set Icon of label. Some more surrounding code when / where you set that might be extremly helpful

Comment: @Jan I edited the question with the block of code to make it easier to understand. I don't really know what to edit there.

Comment: Your code block does not define `HCard` and other variables. What's more, variables should start with a lower case so that they won't be confused with type names. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: They are defined outside of the block to be used elsewhere, and I know but I seem to do that and I just leave it like it :/ @user1803551

Comment: Write a class from scratch that just reads one of the images and displays it. Post the code of that class and tell us if it works or what doesn't work.

Comment: `jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blackjack/zCards/Clubs/" + PCard1 + ".png")));` can you split that in 6 lines, first accessing the resource, then print it's value, then create image, then print it's value and so on?